# OneSignal - How to get PlayerId after user subscribes?

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

In my javascript code I ask user to subscribe for website notifications using OnceSignal service, so I do:

```
    OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications();
```

Then I'm trying to catch PlayerId of subscribed user with the following:

```
    OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.on('notificationPermissionChange', function(permissionChange) {
            var currentPermission = permissionChange.to;

            if (currentPermission == "granted") {
                OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) { 
                    console.log(userId);
                });
            }
        });
```

Then I get that userId and store it in my mysql database so I can send notifications later. But for some reason that userId is different from PlayerId stored on OneSignal Server while the format is the same. Are UserId and PlayerId different things? If it is so, how can I get PlayerId after user subscribes for Pushes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you're seeing an old user ID. The notificationPermissionChange event occurs too early to obtain the user's ID. The event is for analytics only, and if you want to find the user's ID after subscription, use the subscriptionChange event.

SDK Docs Link: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-sdk

Comment: Thank you. They are still appear to be different. If I place OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) { ... inside   OneSignal.push(["getNotificationPermission", function(permission) { or inside   OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function (isSubscribed) {... I get the same value in the console, for example: 3c4d2ae9-de39-4780-92fb-76667f7681ec but on the server it is still different: f2736015-ffca-4cef-bf03-b5708bdb1504

Comment: Ok, I have now understood what is happaning. It gives me an old UserId from the cache. If I clear the cache completely I get proper UserId matching the one from the server. And you are right no notificationPermissionChange  occurs too early, when I clear browser cache I get UserId = null on that event and I get what I need on subscriptionChange event, thank you very much

Comment: Cached? Now I can't tell users to clear cache to use the app. Whats a better solution here?

Answer (score 1):

The below used to work nicely, however of late, haven't been able to get the player id at all when binding to the "subscriptionChange" event.

Infact, in the event listener, nothing after "OneSignal.push" executes.

Tried removing it and went straight to " OneSignal.getUserId", however seems the promise returns nothing.

```js
OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function (isSubscribed) {
            console.log('is subscribed', isSubscribed);
            OneSignal.push(function() { 
              console.log('attempt to get id'); // doesn't get this far
              OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
                console.log('user id', userId); // doesn't get this far                
              });
            });
          });
```

Strange thing is, can get the player id fine if you paste this into the console, only during the callback is nothing returned.

```js
 OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
                console.log('user id', userId);              
              });
```

Seems really weird why the code has just stopped working as we where using this exact code for over a year.

Any suggestions?

Comment: OK got it working, not sure of the exact issue, however, I suspect that this was not working for some time however went un-noticed.

Ended up creating a new site with new list and enabled "My site is not fully HTTPS".

Then uploaded the service worker files, configured  service workers (hosted in sub dirs and setting service worker headers for /) - Obviously we don't host 3rd party libs in a root dir!

Now she's working again. My guess is when it was working it was over http.

Answer (score -1):

Hello this is how I got it done with js
Greetings, I hope it works for you.

```
window.plugins.OneSignal
            .addSubscriptionObserver(function(state){
            var datos = JSON.stringify(state);
            var valor = JSON.parse(datos); 
            var playerId = valor.to.userId
            console.log( playerId + ' *_IF_**PLAYER ID***' )                
});
```